# Run a method if test fails on Junit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have added a method to my Selenium framework that takes a screenshot at the end of a test, but as some tests don't run all the way to the end due to failing. i'd like to implement a rule to run this screenshot method if the test fails.

Something like:

```
@Rule
public Failure fail = new Failure();

if (fail)
{
    // Method
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can possibly use `TestWatcher` this one have hooks for failed and success results. And you can add your hooks logic

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class Test1 {

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watch = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, 4);
    }

}
```

Comment: Fine answer for specifying right structure, but how to set it up in Android Studio? I have tried this and all is compiled OK, but when I test, failed-method is newer called even if test fails. For me this is important, because at fails situation I must call external server to restart service, but now I must do this manually, so automatic testing is not possible.

Comment: @ReijoKorhonen this should work just fine. By anychance you are mixing junit with testng? Please make sure all imports are from org.junit and try.